# Getting the parameter-less type

Tags: types, julia

I need to get the parameter-less version of a type. For example, lets say I have `x = [0.1,0.2,0.3]`. Then `typeof(x)==Array{Float64,1}`. How do I make a function (or does one exist?) `parameterless_type(x) == Array`? I need to get this in a generic form in order to access the constructor without the type parameters in it.

Comment: `typeof(x).name` gave me `Array`. It might do the trick, but not be officially sanctioned Julia.

Comment: ColorTypes.jl does this and many related tricks, might be a useful model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on 0.5

```
julia> typeof(a)
Array{Float64,1}

julia> (typeof(a).name.primary)([1 2 3])
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3
```

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to tholy's comment and the `ColorTypes.jl` package, a solution for 0.6 is:

```
julia> (typeof(a).name.wrapper)([1 2 3])
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
```

**Edit 2:**

Fengyang Wang convinced me, that using `typename` is necessary. In particular, `Array{Int}.name` fails on 0.6 because `Array{Int}` is now of type `UnionAll`. A definition working on 0.5 and 0.6 is

```
using Compat.TypeUtils: typename

if :wrapper in fieldnames(TypeName)
    parameterless_type(T::Type) = typename(T).wrapper
else
    parameterless_type(T::Type) = typename(T).primary
end

parameterless_type(x) = parameterless_type(typeof(x))
```

With that, it is

```
parameterless_type([0.1,0.2,0.3]) == Array
parameterless_type(Array{Int}) == Array
```

Comment: This fails on 0.6. It's best to use a library function instead of field access.

Comment: @FengyangWang There is no library function for this use case. Therefore, I see no problem in using the above approach. Of course, I would wrap such code in my own function (`ColorTypes.jl` calls it `basetype`), so that it is easy to fix if it breaks with an update.

Comment: For at least the `.name` field access, the library function `typename` should be used. It is very brittle to access `.name` as can be seen if you try this on `VecOrMat{Int}`.

Comment: @FengyangWang `typeof(Union{Int, Float64}).name.primary == Union` (or `.wrapper` on 0.6) works as expected, while `typename` throws an error. Thus, depending on the actual use case, there might be no "proper way".

Comment: That's because you're doing `Union.name.wrapper` vs. `typename(Union{Int, Float64}).name.wrapper`, which is not the same thing. The `typename` result is correct, as `Union{Int, Float64}` is not an subtype of `Union`.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way, compatible with both 0.5 and 0.6, is to use `Compat`.

```
julia> using Compat

julia> Compat.TypeUtils.typename(Array{Int, 2})
Array

julia> Compat.TypeUtils.typename(Union{Int, Float64})
ERROR: typename does not apply to unions whose components have different typenames
Stacktrace:
 [1] typename(::Union) at ./essentials.jl:119

julia> Compat.TypeUtils.typename(Union{Vector, Matrix})
Array
```

Comment: This returns a `TypeName`. Is there a way (besides `eval`) to call an appropriate constructor on 0.6?

Comment: @Tim The appropriate type can be recovered from the `TypeName` using `.wrapper`; although this kind of direct field access is prone to breakage in the future.